# GitLab pipeline throwing an error "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: gitlab

While trying to run the GitLab pipeline, I am getting an error

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class Testing\GitLab-Runner\builds\EgKZ847y\0\sandeshmms\LearningSelenium..m2.repository"
```

Also, it is giving this message:

```
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted.
```

**Below is the console message:**

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.2.0 (58ba2b95)
  on my-runner1 EgKZ847y
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
Running on HOMEPC...
Getting source from Git repository 00:10
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in D:/Java Testing/GitLab-Runner/builds/EgKZ847y/0/sandeshmms/LearningSelenium/.git/
Checking out 41ee697d as develop...
git-lfs/2.12.1 (GitHub; windows 386; go 1.14.10; git 85b28e06)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache 00:02
Version:      14.2.0
Git revision: 58ba2b95
Git branch:   14-2-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-08-22T19:47:56+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/386
Checking cache for default-14...
Runtime platform                                    arch=386 os=windows pid=5420 revision=58ba2b95 version=14.2.0
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:03
$ echo "Testing Job Triggered"
Testing Job Triggered
$ echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
D:\Java Testing\GitLab-Runner\builds\EgKZ847y\0\sandeshmms\LearningSelenium
$ mvn $MAVEN_OPTS clean test
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Error: Could not find or load main class Testing\GitLab-Runner\builds\EgKZ847y\0\sandeshmms\LearningSelenium..m2.repository
Uploading artifacts for failed job 00:02
Version:      14.2.0
Git revision: 58ba2b95
Git branch:   14-2-stable
GO version:   go1.13.8
Built:        2021-08-22T19:47:56+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/386
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=386 os=windows pid=4312 revision=58ba2b95 version=14.2.0
WARNING: target/surefire-reports/*: no matching files 
ERROR: No files to upload                          
Cleaning up file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

**Below is the complete yaml file:**

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
  # This will suppress any download for dependencies and plugins or upload messages which would clutter the console log.
  # `showDateTime` will show the passed time in milliseconds. You need to specify `--batch-mode` to make this work.
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"

# Cache downloaded dependencies and plugins between builds.
# To keep cache across branches add 'key: "$CI_JOB_NAME"'
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

test job:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - testing
  script:
    - echo "Testing Job Triggered"
    - echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_OPTS clean test'
    - echo "Testing Job Finished"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - target/surefire-reports/*
```

But if I remove the variables section and cache section from the yaml file and in the script section if I give just mvn clean test, then the build runs fine.

Also, it is downloading the maven repository to `'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.m2\repository'`. Any reason why it is downloading to this directory ?

Can anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

The message `No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted.` just means that your GitLab instance isn't configured to use a service like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/serv-s3) or [Min.io](https://min.io) to store your cached items. Without it, the cache can only be stored locally where your Gitlab-Runners are running. This also means that the cache stored on one runner cannot be shared with another runner, which is most likely how you can run into the error you have. You also don't have a `key`, so the runner doesn't know when to download which `cached` items.

Here's an example of a job building NPM dependencies that use the cache and a key for the specific ref name (a branch, commit, or tag):

```yaml
...
Run NPM Install:
  stage: build
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    paths:
      - node_modules
  script:
    - npm ci
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - node_modules
...
```

In this job, for the first pipeline for the branch, commit, or tag under `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME`, it will run `npm ci` and upload it as an artifact for jobs later in the pipeline to use. However, if a pipeline for the same branch, commit, or tag is run again, instead of running `npm ci` it will download the cached `node_modules` directory, and upload that as an artifact.

See [Caching in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) for more information on caching, and [Distributed Caching](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/autoscale.html#distributed-runners-caching) for information on using S3 or Minio to distribute your cache across all runners.

Comment: The m2 repository cache path is `C:\Users\Sandesh Sawant\.m2\repository`. For every job run it downloads the repository. So, to prevent these downloads for every job run, do I have to create m2 folder inside my project directory, download the dependencies there, and then push this project directory to GitLab, which will trigger the pipeline, so, it copies the contents from the remote repo to the builds directory of GitLab runner i.e. inside `D:\Java Testing\GitLab-Runner\builds\EgKZ847y\0\sandeshmms\LearningSelenium` ?

Comment: You'll need to decide when the cache is valid, whether that's only for each branch, for a single, specific branch, etc. and add the `key` like in my post above. If the cache is only valid for each branch it runs for, you can use `key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` like I have above. The `key` field tells the runner when any available cache is valid or not, and if valid, it'll download the cache for the running job. However, your job should also account for the fact that the cache doesn't exist and create whatever it is you're caching.